# Why the second CAA query does not timeout?

Tags: node.js, caching, dns

I have a piece of node.js code which checks the [CAA record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_Certification_Authority_Authorization) of a specific domain.

```
const dns = require('dns-socket')
const defaultDNS = '10.11.1.5'  // My DNS server
const socket = dns()

function checkCaa (domainName) {
  console.log(`domainName: ${domainName}`)
  socket.query({
    questions: [{
      type: 'CAA',
      name: domainName
    }]
  }, 53, defaultDNS, (err, res) => {
    console.error(`Error: ${err}`)
    console.log(`Response: ${JSON.stringify(res)}`)
    socket.destroy()
  })
}

checkCaa('www.babushop.com.tw')
```

`www.babushop.com.tw` is a domain that has no CAA record.

When I execute the above code for the first time, the program outputs:

```
domainName: www.babushop.com.tw
Error: Error: Query timed out
Response: undefined
```

As you can see from the output, it says the query timed out.

I'd like to know why it gives the following output when I run it for the second time:

```
domainName: www.babushop.com.tw
Error: null
Response: {"id":22260,"type":"response","flags":384,"flag_qr":true,"opcode":"QUERY","flag_auth":false,"flag_trunc":false,"flag_rd":true,"flag_ra":true,"flag_z":false,"flag_ad":false,"flag_cd":false,"rcode":"NOERROR","questions":[{"name":"www.babushop.com.tw","type":"CAA","class":"IN"}],"answers":[{"name":"www.babushop.com.tw","type":"CNAME","class":"IN","ttl":42,"flush":false,"data":"s2454.dname.91app.io"},{"name":"s2454.dname.91app.io","type":"CNAME","class":"IN","ttl":42,"flush":false,"data":"proxy.letssl.91app.io"},{"name":"proxy.letssl.91app.io","type":"CNAME","class":"IN","ttl":56,"flush":false,"data":"proxy-letssl-91app-io-196811564.ap-northeast-1.elb.amazonaws.com"}],"authorities":[],"additionals":[]}
```

Is something cached in my DNS server(10.11.1.5 in this case) so that it doesn't time out?

If so, what is it?

This phenomenon makes me difficult to determine whether the CAA query will time out or not.

Answer (score 0):

`babushop.com.tw` does not seem very well configured DNS-wise (see http://dnsviz.net/d/www.babushop.com.tw/dnssec/) that I would not expect being able to retrieve anything useful for this zone. In short, for this domain the problem is clearly not on your side.